# ui datepicker not working as expected on click

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have the following piece if code:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr").live('click', function(){
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")").css("border", "1px solid Green");
});
```

but when I click on a date, the green box isn't being shown. However, when the page loads, the green box is shown as expected.

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you want to have a green border? From your code, it looks like you want the `tr` after the one you clicked to get it. That can be accomplished by simply doing `$(this).next().css("border", "1px solid green");`

Comment: I want to put the green box round a range of dates, that is for that particular week.  The code is working in chrome and Firefox

Comment: Then simply use `$(this).css("border", "1px solid green");`. Since you've attached the event to the `tr`, `$(this)` will reference that week.

Comment: The code isn`t working with IE8.0

Comment: $(this).css("border", "1px solid green"); doesn`t work in chrome and firefox as well\

Comment: The code works. It's just that after you click on a date, the calendar closes. When it subsequently opens, it's not the same HTML anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a bit differently, perhaps more effectively. You could attach a `click` event on the datepicker and find the selected day by looking for the TD with `.ui-datepicker-current-day` class. One other thing is, try to avoid editing css directly; use classes instead.

```
$('.week-picker').datepicker().click(function(event) {
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent().addClass('highlight');
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/YQ2Zw/22/.

---

**Update**

If you also want the selected date not to be highlighted, you can remove the `.ui-state-active` class from the anchor element. E.g.

```
$('.week-picker').datepicker().click(function(event) {
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent().addClass('highlight');
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day a").removeClass('ui-state-active');
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/YQ2Zw/24/.

Comment: I want to set a green box around a range of dates, i.e, the current week of the selected date and not to the date clicked

Comment: what's the difference between "the selected date" and "the date clicked"?

Comment: the date clicked is the selected date.

Comment: Then what is wrong with the jsfiddle? There is a green border around the whole week.

Comment: i'm guess you also want the selected date *not* to be highlighted? See the updated answer.

Comment: have you tested that with IE8.0? My code is working except in IE 8.0.  The new code you have provided isn`t working with IE 8.0 as well.